# Does this "reverse microwave" cool food "without electricity and is 100% sustainable"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics

A recent [Eco News article](https://www.ecoticias.com/en/reverse-microwave/344/) says:

> The “reverse microwave” is already a reality: it works without electricity and will revolutionize our life
>
> [...]
>
> Imagine a reverse microwave to cool food instead of heating it. It has just been invented, and it works without electricity and does not emit polluting gases. It’s clear: it’s going to revolutionize our kitchens.
>
> [...]
>
> The reverse microwave was something we’ve been asking for for years, but this one also ***works without electricity and is 100% sustainable***.

They're describing an [electrocaloric cooling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocaloric_effect) recently discovered by researchers at the Luxembourg Institute of Science and Technology (LIST). However...

> The electrocaloric cooling system developed by LIST consists of electrocaloric capacitors and liquid coolant which make rapid heat transfer. Heating of the fluid in the capacitors, causes cooling of the system ***via application of electric field***.

Doesn't that require electricity?

LIST's paper ['High cooling performance in a double-loop electrocaloric heat pump'](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.adi5477) begins...

> Electrocaloric materials pump heat out of a system through a phase transition driven by ***changing an electric field***.

That sounds an awful lot like it needs [alternating current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) electricity.

> We present an electrocaloric cooler with a maximum temperature span of 20.9 kelvin and a maximum cooling power of 4.2 watts under the ***moderate applied electric field of 10 volts per micrometer*** without any observed breakdown.

Seems like it uses electricity.

Can LIST's new electrocaloric cooling effect ("reverse microwave") cool without electricity and is it 100% sustainable?

Comment: To whether it's notable, it managed to make it into my Google News feed. :shrug: I'm fairly certain the answer is "No". The paper summary mentions "the material does not break down under repeated field cycling" which I'm guessing is where the "100% sustainable" claim comes from.

Comment: @Schwern: I was going to close because EcoNews appears to be just one dude, and their Facebook and Instagram feeds have barely any viewership. On Twitter, though, they have a big viewership (Should I be suspicious about bots?). If it made it into your feed, that is a sign that they have reach.

Comment: @Oddthinking I just earned "Notable Question", 4000 views, it seems you were right.

Comment: I find it interesting that "ten volts per micrometer" is described as a "moderate electric field".

Comment: @Mark  I'm inclined to agree, especially after shifting units to 10 kiloVolts / mm or 10 MegaVolts / meter.

Comment: While others parts of the topic have already been debunked, I do want to point out that "not using electricity" can _to some subjective degree_ be used in the sense of "not making use of electricity on the communal network" (i.e. the thing you pay your provider for. It's not pedantically correct, but if the surrounding context is one of saving on your power bill (and this is clear to the reader), I'd be inclined to allow "not using electricity".

Comment: @Flater No matter how it does it, It needs energy to move heat from hot to cold. If it doesn't get that from the electrical grid, does it have a hand crank?

Comment: @Schwern: Without electricity is not the same as without power (but "power" is also a good ambiguity to point out). Also, my comment was about the ambiguity of "electricity" meaning the physics concept versus the grid (i.e. power bills). For example, if I bought a bunch of batteries I would not list that under "electricity" on my budgeting tool. A lot of sustainability articles focus on not drawing power from the grid (or reducing it) and I was pointing out that the authors may have gotten into the habit of referring to that specifically rather than the physics concept.

Answer (score 63):

The claim, to no-one's surprise, is false.

Electrocaloric heat-pumping requires energy to be supplied (e.g. by electricity). The alternative would be to break the [Second Law of Thermodynamics](https://www.mittensheatpumps.co.uk/heat-pumps/thermodynamics-information/).

The Econews article appears to be a confused report about [November 2023 announcements](https://www.list.lu/en/news/new-cooling-mechanism-set-to-revolutionize-conventional-environmentally-harmful-refrigeration-techno) of a recent paper in Science, [*High cooling performance in a double-loop electrocaloric heat pump*](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.adi5477).

The Science article doesn't claim that no electricity is required, but talks about its *potential* efficiency:

> Moreover, the maximum coefficient of performance, even taking into account energy expended on fluid pumping, reaches 64% of Carnot’s efficiency as long as energy is properly recovered.

Comment: Regardless of power needs, could one actually use this process to build a reverse microawave that cools food?

Comment: @quarague: It's a new technology. No-one has tried yet.  So I can't provide an empirical answer to that question. Anything else is guesswork.

Comment: I had a conjecture: That this article was originally written in Spanish and translated to English, and the errors were introduced during the translation phase, but I am unable to find a corresponding article on their Spanish page.

Comment: @quarague every heat pump is both a heater and a cooler. It just depends on which side you use and which side you expose to the environment. So yes, it could be used as a *refrigerator*.

Comment: And this efficiency IS actually significant. There's a reason why dryers are almost entirely different systems compared to machines made just 10-15 years back. I think there were at least 2 major innovations that changed the efficiencies of these machines at such a significant level that they were commercially viable.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan: There is a lot more to that question than whether the technology could cool down a spherical cow in a vacuum. Would the device be as small, as reliable, as safe, as efficient, as long lasting, as "quiet" and as cheap as a compressor? Petri dish style experiments don't show the technology could be used for food.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Would you say that a conventional microwave oven is both a heater and a cooler? If so, does that mean it could be used to cool food?

Comment: @LarsH a microwave oven is not a heat pump.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan's comment is irrelevant here. In case you haven't noticed, microwaving your food does not make your kitchen chilly. *Almost all* heating devices (microwaves, ovens, toasters, electric or gas fireplaces, water kettles, space heaters, seat warmers) are *not* heat pumps. Fridges, AC units, and some fraction of fairly new building heating are heat pumps.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg this answer is about “electrocaloric heat-pumping” which *is*, no surprise, a kind of heat pumping. Maybe someone should have said explicitly that there is no such thing as a “reverse microwave”, but what the article linked in the question calls “reverse microwave” is electrocaloric heat-pumping which is not even remotely something like a “reverse microwave”.

Comment: @vsfDawg I would be inclined to agree, but LM apparently thought his comment was relevant, which could mean he meant something different by "heat pump" than what I think it means. Hence my question. Maybe I should have elaborated on that more. Holger's comment about the described technology not being like a "reverse microwave" helps clarify the issue.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg The fact that LM's comment is highly upvoted suggests that a lot of people think it is somehow relevant. A big source of confusion for me, and perhaps for you, was the "reverse microwave" label, which LM implicitly affirmed by saying "yes" to quarague's question about building a reverse microwave. I suspect he meant to say yes only about technology to cool food, not about building a reverse microwave.

Comment: @LarsH The article is talking about a new kind of heat pump. It's bizarre they chose "reverse microwave", it doesn't use microwaves and we have a word for an appliance that cools food: a refrigerator, and refrigerator is an insulated box with a heat pump.

Comment: @Schwern Agreed. It sounds like the article writer likes to make attention-grabbing claims without much respect for reality. This answer begins with a statement that "the claim" is false, where the claim is about a "reverse microwave" technology. As Holger suggested, it would have been less confusing if the answer had clarified that the following discussion about electrocaloric heat pumping technology did not refer to the claimed "reverse microwave" (whatever that might mean).

Comment: @LarsH I thought I made that pretty clear in the question, but I see we did not connect the dots.

Comment: I see the phrase "reverse microwave" as an analogy - it is like a microwave oven in that the hypothetical technology can change the temperature of food, but it is the reverse because it chills food rather than heating it. Analogies are always limited. In this case, it is unlike a microwave oven in that it doesn't use microwave radiation. Arguing that [a claim is false because the analogy isn't perfect](https://www.txst.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/faulty-analogy) would be foolish.

Comment: @Oddthinking More specifically, the analogy as I read it is that this putative device is to a microwave as a refrigerator is to an oven (or it is to a refrigerator as a microwave is to an oven) – not in terms of science, but in terms of application. An oven requires time to warm up and cooks food fairly slowly; a refrigerator requires time to become cold and cools food down quite slowly. A microwave requires no warm-up and cooks food very fast; this device would presumably not need to become cold and would cool food down very fast.

Comment: There's a lot of misunderstanding of this device here: you could in theory use it to make a refrigerator that doesn't need coolant or compressors, but it would still be a refrigerator that works by cooling some of its surfaces down (while heating others up more) and food inside is mostly cooled by sitting in enclosed air that touches those cold surfaces, at about the same speed and in exactly the same way as a fridge today (or icebox of yesteryear). There are no beams or circuits of cold energy passing through the contents.

Comment: The hypothetical advantages are eliminating the need for a large motor and the mechanical system that moves the coolant. Smaller, quieter heat pumps with fewer moving parts to fail, and (in theory) less energy wasted on driving the mechanical systems. This could be great in a variety of applications, absolutely none of which bear even a passing conceptual connection to a "reverse microwave".

Comment: @JayMcEh: 'absolutely none of which bear even a passing conceptual connection to a "reverse microwave".' I have already explained how there is a passing conceptual connection. I have argued that demanding the analogy to be perfect is foolish. You have argued that the analogy isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer here already, but it doesn't really address the appropriateness of the "reverse microwave" description. I would argue that it is an *inappropriate* description, even though it is not completely indefensible. The [Science paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.adi5477) describes a refrigeration method that uses a special material along with a varying electric field. The changing field causes one side of the material to get hotter and the other side to get colder, and you can use the cold side for refrigeration purposes. This is like a regular refrigerator, except that there are no moving parts.

Here is why the "reverse microwave" description is inappropriate (misleading may be a better word): Microwave ovens heat things *quickly*, using EM waves that directly get inside the food and shake the water molecules. The method in the paper is just another way to cool a refrigerator. Things won't get cold any faster. There is no kind of radiation that can slow down the water molecules, and so no way to cool food faster than heat can be conducted through the food.

Here is the sense in which it is defensible: Like a microwave oven, it uses a varying electromagnetic field to change the temperature of something, and so it doesn't have moving parts. But it does this by moving heat from one side of it to another, not magically creating coldness, and only works for a specially tuned material. I only call it "defensible" here because I suspect there are well-meaning people who use that description and I want to convey what I think they mean. It's really not a good description.

Comment: 1) "*There is no kind of radiation that can slow down the water molecules*" There is! [Laser cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling). Not practical for the home kitchen. 2) The microwave analogy is even more strained. A microwave works by heating water, whereas the heat pump the article describes works by moving heat. 3) Maybe they got it from the ["reverse microwave oven" rapid drink cooler](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/technology-51028494).

Comment: A standard refrigerator also uses a varying electromagnetic field to change the temperature of something (presumably reducing), so by your logic is also defensibly a "reverse microwave". So is a room with a ceiling fan, assuming the contents are damp. It's a more comprehensible analogy than describing it as "inflatable penicillin" or somesuch, but the ways it misleads are more numerous and salient than the ways it reveals.